# Sending out multiple Reports in one E-Mail in ServiceNow using the Scheduled Report function

Tags: report, schedule, servicenow

I have created 5 Reports for a specific service which I would like to send out by mail using the scheduled report function. I could send out one report easily to my mail, but sine the field for the reports is a single selection field I am afraid that I can only send out one report at max per mail.

Is there any way to group my reports or any other workaround?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce report-related email volume, you can schedule multiple reports to be sent in a single email. Each report is included in the email as an attachment. Other than email attachment limitations, there is no limit to the number of reports that can be added to a single email.

To schedule multiple reports, use the 'Included in Email' related list to create additional scheduled reports.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer from Siri, it's a bit convoluted but can be done.

See these KBs

- Fuji and earlier: https://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Scheduling_and_Publishing_Reports#Scheduling_Multiple_Reports
- Genava: https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-performance-analytics-and-reporting/page/use/advanced_reporting/task/t_ScheduleAReport.html

They are the same process, but from the Fuji example

> To reduce report-related email volume, you can schedule multiple
>   reports to be sent in a single email. Each report is included in the
>   email as an attachment. Other than email attachment limitations, there
>   is no limit to the number of reports that can be added to a single
>   email.

To schedule multiple reports:

- Navigate to **Reports > Scheduled Reports**.
- Click **New**.
- Define the report as described under [Scheduling Reports](https://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Scheduling_and_Publishing_Reports#Scheduling_Reports).
- Save the record.
- Use the **Included in Email** related list to create additional scheduled reports.

  - Each report you add to the **Included in Email** related list must have its own schedule. This allows you to send different reports to one or more of the recipients of the previously identified reports, each with its own schedule.
- Click **Update**.